# Thinking Sphinx text search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx

Hi people I'm having a problem with one search that I'm making in one of my projects. I am new using Sphinx and the problem is when I make a search like = "ipad" it work perfect but when I put "ipa" the full text search seems no to work the way I want cause I'm not receiving anything back.

```
my_variable = self.search searchTxt, :match_mode => :any, :sort_mode => :extended, :order => sortType, :page => page, :per_page => perPage
```

Am I doing something wrong with the search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some additional configuration necessary to search with wildcards, as explained in the [documentation](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/common_issues.html#wildcards).